# Javascript: из одномерного объекта в древовидную структуру по разделителю

Tags: javascript, объекты

Здравствуйте.
Необходимо представить вывод из базы данных в виде многомерного объекта.

```
var rows = [
    {
        'id' : 1,
        'type' : 'text',
        'last.body' : 'Привет',
        'last.from.id' : 55,
        'last.from.name' : 'Пользователь 1'
    },
    {
        'id' : 2,
        'type' : 'text',
        'last.body' : 'Добрый день',
        'last.from.id' : 56,
        'last.from.name' : 'Пользователь 2'
    },
];
```

В данный момент реализовал в лоб, но думаю что есть более простой и не костыльный метод подобного разворачивания объекта. Да и вложенность не стоит ограничивать.

```
var level2 = /(\w+)\.(\w+)/i;
var level3 = /(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)/i;
var items = [];
for (var index in rows) {
    items[index] = {};
    for (var key in rows[index]) {
        if ((match3 = level3.exec(key)) !== null) {
            if (!(match3[1] in items[index])) items[index][match3[1]] = {};
            if (!(match3[2] in items[index][match3[1]])) items[index][match3[1]][match3[2]] = {};
            items[index][match3[1]][match3[2]][match3[3]] = rows[index][key];
        } else if ((match2 = level2.exec(key)) !== null) {
            if (!(match2[1] in items[index])) items[index][match2[1]] = {};
            items[index][match2[1]][match2[2]] = rows[index][key];
        } else {
            items[index][key] = rows[index][key];
        }
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 3));
```

Выведет:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "text",
      "last": {
         "body": "Привет",
         "from": {
            "id": 55,
            "name": "Пользователь 1"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "text",
      "last": {
         "body": "Добрый день",
         "from": {
            "id": 56,
            "name": "Пользователь 2"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вариант с использованием функций [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) и [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var rows = [{
  'id': 1,
  'type': 'text',
  'last.body': 'Привет',
  'last.from.id': 55,
  'last.from.name': 'Пользователь 1'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'type': 'text',
  'last.body': 'Добрый день',
  'last.from.id': 56,
  'last.from.name': 'Пользователь 2'
}, ];

var mapped = rows.map(function(row) {

  return Object.keys(row).reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    cur.split('.').reduce(function(a, c, i, ar) {
      if (i == ar.length - 1) a[c] = row[cur];

      return a[c] = a[c] || {};

    }, acc);
    return acc;
  }, {});

});

document.body.innerHTML = 'src: <pre>'+ JSON.stringify(rows,null, 2)+'</pre>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'res: <pre>'+ JSON.stringify(mapped,null, 2)+'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```js
var row = {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "text",
    "last.body": "Привет",
    "last.from.id": 55,
    "last.from.name": "Пользователь 1"
};
var result = {};

for (var key in row) {
    var keys    = key.split(".");
    var last    = keys.length - 1;
    var current = result;

    for (var index = 0; index < last; index++) {
        current = current[keys[index]] || (current[keys[index]] = {})
    }
    current[keys[last]] = row[key];
}
```